# How to set width of empty primefaces datatable

Tags: java, primefaces

I am using primefaces datatable. How to set width when the table is empty ? because in this case the table smaller when they have some record, I try use style

```
style="width: 150%"
```

or

```
style="width: 200px"
```

but with no success.

And it is possible to change default text "No records found." to something else ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<p:dataTable style="width:25px;">` will change the width of the table, but the column headers and the message displayed when there are no records also effects the width of the table.

Check the text in your column headers. The text will not line break between words, so the column will have a minium width based on the header text.

```
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="This is a long column header" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.value}" />
</p:column>
```

[image]

The `No Records Found` message will line break between words

[image]

so it will only effect the width if one of the words in the message is to long.

```
<p:dataTable style="width:25px;" emptyMessage="thisisalongmessagefornodata">
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<p:column style="white-space: nowrap">
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<p:dataTable>` has a `emptyMessage` attribute. Set it to a String value and it will be displayed when the source data collection for your table is empty.

Answer (score 2):

For empty message:

```
 <p:dataTable emptyMessage="No records found." style="text-align: center;" ...
```

For "blank" line:

```
 <p:dataTable emptyMessage="&nbsp;" style="text-align: center;" ...
```

And if it's important to have the columns aligned left, do:

```
<p:column rendered="true" style="text-align: left;">
```